# unable to view previous version items in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365, version

I am working on SharePoint file versions and i created a SharePoint site on which i have uploaded a 5Mb size of excel file. I tried to create some version of by editing the file. After creating some versions in version history. I tried to view version of file with the version ID of 2.0 but it is not showing me hyperlink on name to view the file.

Here,

Versions of file:

[image: versions of file]

Version of ID = 2.0

[image]

Can someone please tell me how can i view previous versions of the file in view mode?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the **libraryName** in code below, then add the code into script editor web part in document library DispForm.aspx page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var libraryName="Shared Documents";
    setNameField(libraryName);
})
function setNameField(libraryName){

    var itemID=getUrlParameter("ID");
    var versionID=getUrlParameter("VersionNo");
    if(itemID!=""&&versionID!=""){
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('"+libraryName+"')/Items("+itemID+")/versions("+versionID+")?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var versionFileUrl=data.d.FileRef.replace(libraryName,"_vti_history/"+versionID+"/"+libraryName);
                var linkFileHtml="<a href='"+versionFileUrl+"'>"+data.d.FileLeafRef+"</a>";
                $(".ms-standardheader:contains('Name')").closest("td").next().html(linkFileHtml);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
}
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(decodeURIComponent(location.search));
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
</script>
```

[image]